# Compare data within a string separated by comma without using explode

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, explode

Is there any way that I can compare if a user id is present in deleted_by_id without going through explode function and just use eloquent directly? I am using laravel 4.2 btw. Below is a sample table:

```
messages    
+-----------------------------+------------------+
+ id | message                + deleted_by_id    +
+-----------------------------+------------------+
+  1 | hello                  + 65,72            +
+  2 | thank you              + 54,33,89         +
+-----------------------------+------------------+
```

I am trying to compare if a user id is present within deleted_by_id so the message will show up on the trash view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no `like` or `regex`, but `find_in_set` (I guess it's **MySQL**):

```
YourModel::whereRaw('find_in_set(?, deleted_by_id)', [$user_id])->get();
```

And obviously suggestion - normalize the db ;)

Comment: Thank you for suggesting to normalize the database, I think it's the best solution I can do. your answer using find_in_set did not return any error neither any results.

Comment: yes, that works great!. I added withTrashed() before get() because I also have a deleted_at field in my table which already had values. Obviously I cannot force data in the result with deleted_at values, so adding withTrashed() works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `SELECT` statement with the `LIKE` operator as one approach, but this would produce unexpected results as your user id value grew. Another approach would be to use the `REGEX` feature of `MySQL`

[MySQL Regex](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

To add to this, since you want to use Eloquent, you could try the `whereRaw()` statement with Regex...

```
Message::whereRaw("deleted_by_id REGEX 8{1}9{1}"); //find 89
```

This is untested, and you would have to update the Regex each time based on what you were looking for, but only option I could see with Eloquent.

Ultimately, your best option is to rethink your table structure so that you can store each user id on its own row.

[MySQL Regex Pattern Matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

Comment: thank you. I agree with you that it will have a problem using LIKE as my user id value grew. I haven't tried Regex yet but I am looking if i can use eloquent directly or a combination of eloquent and Regex.

Comment: updated my answer to provide another option, but still far from great if you ask me

Comment: sorry, I can't seem to make it working using wherRaw or I just don't know how to use whereRaw. Maybe in the future I will restructure the table if I need to.

Comment: Thank you for giving me option to reconsider to restructure the table, I think it would be a good solution to my problem.